# Boltzmann distribution derivation from Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability

### Context

In the derivation of the Boltzmann factor and the canonical partition function based essentially on Lagrange multipliers presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)), the equalities,
\begin{align*}
p_j &= \frac{1}{Z} e^{\frac{\lambda_2 E_j}{k_B}} \\
Z &= \sum_j e^{\frac{\lambda_2 E_j}{k_B}}
\end{align*}
are established, where $E_j$ refers to the energy of a microstate, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $\lambda_2$ is the remaining undetermined multiplier. Then, using the Gibbs entropy $S = - k_B \sum_j p_j \ln(p_j)$ along with some algebra,
\begin{gather*}
S = -\lambda_2 U + k_B \ln(Z) 
\end{gather*}
Finally, the article suggests the derivative,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial U} = - \lambda_2
\end{gather*}
without further work. Note that the article also improperly uses a total derivative instead of a partial here as the whole point is to make the identification $\frac{\partial S}{\partial U} = - \lambda_2 = \frac{1}{T}$.

### My Question

My question comes from the details of working out the partial derivative. I obtained,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial U} &= - \lambda_2 - U \frac{\partial \lambda_2}{\partial U} + \frac{k_B}{Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial U} \\
&= - \lambda_2 - U \frac{\partial \lambda_2}{\partial U} + \frac{1}{Z} \sum_j e^{\frac{\lambda_2 E_j}{k_B}} \left[ E_j \frac{\partial \lambda_2}{\partial U} + \lambda_2 \frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} \right] \\
&= - \lambda_2 + \frac{1}{Z} \sum_j e^{\frac{\lambda_2 E_j}{k_B}}  \lambda_2 \frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} 
\end{align*}
where we have used the statistical definition of $U$ and the equalities above to cancel one of the derivative terms involving $\frac{\partial \lambda_2}{\partial U}$. It is at this point that I have a question. Clearly, for this to work, we must have $ \frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$. But I cannot seem to really justify this step to myself. Is it simply that the energies of the particular microstates do not explicitly depend on the average energy? How would one justify this?

Comment: First off, a similar version also holds for non-physical applications of the Max-Ent principle. Second, yes, why do you think the micro states depend on $U$? I mean they are fixed by the kind of system you consider and "external" parameters like $N,V,\ldots$. Once these things are fixed, you obtain $U$ as the average of the energies with respect to some probability distribution.

Comment: I don’t think they depend on U, but I’m not convinced I can just assert that derivative vanishes in general.

Comment: This statement is contradictory.

Comment: BTW: It is a basic fact in the theory of Lagrange multipliers that the derivative of the constrained (say) maximum function with respect to a constraint is the corresponding multiplier... See e.g. [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/applications-of-multivariable-derivatives/constrained-optimization/a/interpretation-of-lagrange-multipliers).

Comment: Could you clarify your remark on the cost function? How does that apply to this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clearly, for this to work, we must have $ \frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$. But I cannot seem to really justify this step to myself. Is it simply that the energies of the particular microstates do not explicitly depend on the average energy? How would one justify this?

This is because when we write
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}
$$
with the intention of getting inverse of thermodynamic temperature, we have to assume that all the other thermodynamic state variables that $S$ depends on are constant; otherwise the derivative need not be function of temperature. In thermodynamics, $S$ is function of at least $U,V,N$, so the derivative is actually

$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\bigg{|}_{V,N} = \frac{1}{T}.
$$

Assuming constant $V,N$ in quantum theory implies constant Hamiltonian, and thus constant energy levels $E_j$. Changing $U$ in this partial derivative is thus allowed to happen only via changing the probabilities $\rho_j$'s, not via changing the energy levels $E_j$'s.

Comment: That connection back to quantum stat mech is a really good one. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Imo, your doubt is related to the assumption that the partial derivative of the energy of a microstate, $(E_j$), with respect to the total energy, $(U$), is zero, i.e., $(\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$).

In the context of statistical mechanics, the assumption $(\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$) is essentially an assumption about the statistical ensemble you are working with. Specifically, it assumes that the energy levels of the microstates are not influenced by the total energy of the system, (U). This assumption is valid for certain types of ensembles, such as the microcanonical ensemble or the canonical ensemble.

The microcanonical ensemble describes an isolated system with a fixed total energy, (U). In this ensemble, the energy of each microstate $(E_j$) is a constant because the total energy is fixed, and the system cannot exchange energy with its surroundings. Therefore, $(\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$) in this ensemble.

The canonical ensemble describes a system in contact with a heat bath at a constant temperature, $(T$). In this ensemble, the energy levels $(E_j$) of the microstates are typically assumed to be fixed properties of the system and not influenced by the total energy $(U$). This assumption is reasonable when dealing with macroscopic systems where the interactions between particles are weak, and the energy levels do not significantly change with variations in the total energy.

So, the assumption $(\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U} = 0$) is justified in the context of these ensembles. Buuuut, it's important to note that this assumption *might* not hold in all situations. For systems with strong interactions or where the energy levels are explicitly dependent on the total energy, this assumption *may not* be valid, and you would need to consider more complex models.

Comment: Why should the energies be (functionally) dependent on the average energy?

Comment: I like this answer, especially since the idea that the microstates are “levels” really emphasizes why averages over them should not cause them to change. I think this statement is pretty much given in the microcanonical ensemble, but it’s a little trickier in the canonical. Does this effectively just say that the position of the level for a given micro state is invariant to how much energy your system happens to have? If so, I feel slightly foolish for my question.

Comment: *"For systems with strong interactions or where the energy levels are explicitly dependent on the total energy, this assumption may not be valid, and you would need to consider more complex models."* Can you give an example for a system where this assumption is not valid?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The assumption *may not be valid* is in strongly interacting quantum systems, particularly in strongly correlated electron systems in condensed matter physics. In such systems, the energy levels of individual particles (e.g., electrons) can depend on the total energy of the system, leading to nontrivial and energy-dependent interactions between particles. I'll ellaborate on it.

Comment: In some materials, particularly in certain types of high-temperature superconductors and strongly correlated electron systems, the interactions between electrons are so strong that they significantly affect the energy levels and behaviour of individual electrons.  In these materials, the energy levels of electrons may depend on the total energy of the system due to the strong electron-electron interactions. This energy dependence can lead to the formation of exotic phases of matter, such as Mott insulators, where the system behaves as an insulator even when it should nominally be conducting.

Comment: In such systems, the assumption $\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U}$ = 0 breaks down because the energy levels (quantized energy states) of electrons are not fixed but are influenced by the total energy, including the interactions between electrons. As a result, the energy landscape and behavior of individual particles become highly nontrivial and can depend on the system's total energy.

Comment: I don't understand why the "strong interaction" in a Mott insulator would lead to the energy levels being dependent on the total energy. Can you give a reference for this claim?

Comment: What I meant is that Mott insulators are primarily characterized by the localization of electrons due to strong on-site Coulomb repulsion, which creates an energy gap between the filled and empty electronic states. The energy gap is typically seen as a function of the material's parameters (such as the strength of the on-site Coulomb repulsion) but is not directly dependent on the total energy of the system. A source for this- (DOI BTW) 10.1103/RevModPhys.70.1039

Comment: If it is "not directly dependent on the total energy of the system" (your words!) then why would $\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial U}\neq 0$ in this case? Your reference is just a generic reference on Mott transition, if your *particular* claim is supported by it, please point out where specifically.

Comment: @ACuriousMind energy levels in QT in general depend on available volume, if that is dependent on total energy, then energy levels are. E.g. equilibrium radiation in a box; greater energy at the same $T$ means bigger box, and that means different, more closely spaced energy levels.

Comment: @JánLalinský $U$ here is not the "total", but average energy. It is given as a constraint, along with e.g. $N,V$ in the canonical ensemble. If you fix $T$, then $U$ is fixed and vice versa, that is exactly the interplay between the Lagrangian multipliers and constraints. The energy levels do not depend on $U$ - the latter is something we impose from the outset. Doing Max-Ent means that we want to find a probability distribution maximizing entropy under the said constraint (if the constraint is impossible to fulfill, there is no solution, but okay).

Comment: The energy levels in turn are determined solely by the Hamiltonian $H$, which in turn depends on $N$ and, as you correctly pointed out, $V$ (and, well, boundary conditions and possible further specifications).

Comment: @CarnotEngine > *"In this ensemble, the energy of each microstate ($E_j$) is a constant because the total energy is fixed, and the system cannot exchange energy..."* This explanation is wrong, because $U$ is not total energy, but average of total energy, and furthermore $U$ is constant only in the variation process when seeking $\rho_j$'s. For any single system, $U$ can change and then $E_j$ can change as well. The correct explanation is in subsequent paragraphs - we *assume* $E_j$'s do not change when changing $U$, which is correct if $U$ is changed while $V$ is maintained constant.